# Restarting all sound services and their configure settings

Tags: audio

I am working on OpenSuse 12.3, to get sound in here I have to go the yast settings and reinstall the sound card interface to get the sound working.
I noticed that , sometimes it is enough to remove the private directories of the sound server -- that is like .pulseaudio or .alsa . Problem is I cannot find them anymore.
What is general way of restarting the sound services under Linux ?
Notice : I want to have one chain of commands setting everything : all those systems :\ : 
[image: http://www.tuxradar.com/files/LXF130.audio.layers.png]

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```